# How can I use selenium to iterate over pages on a Website?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a piece of code in Python to scrape the following website for all the listed urls.

https://yavapai.arizonataxsale.com/index.cfm?folder=previewitems

What I've run into is that the site uses javascript, where you page through to access all the data. I failed using beautifulSoup because it is unable to iterate through all the pages since there is only one website url and it can't interact with javascript to go page by page. I tried the select function but couldn't get it to work.

I've started to try to figure out selenium, but haven't had any luck either, I'm not very familiar with this package.

Been completely stumped on this for the last week, I know I'm missing something!If anyone is able to help or point me in the right direction I would be really grateful!

Comment: Please provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have Selenium click on something and then wait for the next page to load to scrape it even if it is the same URL. I have done something similar myself.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that may be helpful for getting started. I wanted to extract all links from the page https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets?topic=6571f26dc009674feb726be9

What you need to do first is to explore the webpage manually from your browser, to check if the clickable parts of the page where inside "article" anchors. To do so, right-click on the part you want to scrape and choose "inspect" inside your web browser.

Here is the script I used to extract the links:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

url = 'https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets?topic=6571f26dc009674feb726be9'


# Set up the driver
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode (no GUI)
# ^ Uncomment this line to visually inspect the page loading
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Disable GPU acceleration, often needed in headless mode
options.add_argument('--window-size=1200x600')  # Set window size to a reasonable value

# Get the page
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# Get the page
driver.get(url)
# Allow some time for JavaScript to execute and load content
time.sleep(3)
# Get the elements with tag "article"
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'article')
```

The links are correctly extracted:

```
# Print the number of elements found
print(f"Found {len(elements)} elements matching the pattern (tag: article).")

# Extract the links from the elements
# https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/information/
for element in elements:
    link = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a").get_attribute("href")
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
Found 7 elements matching the pattern (tag: article).
https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets/6569b4473bedf2e7abad3b72
https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets/656dab84db1bdf627a40eaae
https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets/6569b51ae64326786e4e8e1a
https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets/6569b3d7d193b4daf2b43edc
https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets/6569ad61106d1679c93cdf77
https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets/6569af36ba0c3d2f9d4bf98c
https://meteo.data.gouv.fr/datasets/6569b4a48a4161faec6b2779
```

The driver is the object used to navigate in the website, and `find_elements` allows you to extract elements following a certain pattern (see https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/).

Here, for example, you can ask the driver to click on the first article (and then to follow the first link):

```
elements[0].click()
time.sleep(3)
```

`time_sleep` is useful to let the time for the content of the page being loaded.